# Some -> iPhone synonyms are goofy

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

I found a bunch of tag synonyms that aren't right:

iphone × 170734     facebook-pictures × 3

iphone × 170734     uitoolbar × 650

iphone × 170734     tabbarcontroller × 149

iphone × 170734     uicollectionview × 667

The bottom three should probably be -> cocoa or cocoa-touch.
Not sure about the top one.

Comment: The bottom 3 are not synonyms for cocoa or cocoa-touch as they are a small part of the latter

Comment: True they are not "synonyms" in the true sense of the word, however, almost any question tagged with those extremely narrow tags should be tagged with cocoa-touch. But I can see them not being linked, too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted the synonyms (not the tags themselves, just the mappings). These seem to me that whoever suggested them doesn't understand the concept of a tag synonym.